# MySQL trigger equivalent in rethinkDB

Tags: php, mysql, asynchronous, triggers, rethinkdb

I'm developing an application in php. I was thinking of using rethinkDB for this project. Everything looks good so far, however i was wondering if there is any way to implement an equivalent of mysql triggers in rethinkDB.

For example,
If an entry from withdrawal table is updated from 0 to 1, reduce the value in amount field of withdrawal table from the balance field of users table

Is this possible? Is there an equivalent?
I've read of changefeeds in rethinkDB, but since php is not asynchronous or event based, i was wondering how it would be implemented? rethinkDB can push data, but if i push it to a script on php, that would be no different from just doing it manually in a script when the action is performed.

I hope someone can shed some light on this for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing like triggers in RethinkDB. So, you have 2 ways to do this:

1. Use changefeeds.
2. Update it manually.

Changefeeds is mostly the same as doing it manually. But it helps you to separate logic. So, for example, you can create another service/demon which, basically, will represent triggers logic:

1. It will subscribe on changes.
2. Update needed records.